# Windows 2003 print server shows printer shared name instead of printer name's

Tags: network-printer, windows-server-2003, print-server

When I try to add a printer from my printer server I get this list with printer shared names:

[image: Printer shared name list]

Instead of this list of printer names:

[image: Printer name list]

EDIT: Until one week ago, when I added a printer to a user from the print server I always get the "Printer name list" when I typed the print server IP. This list is the printer names that the printers have in the print server.

Now I'm getting the "Printer shared name list" and I want the "**Printer name list**".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Doesn't the dialog you are showing say (in English) "Shared by Name" ?  As a windows print driver author.. Microsoft has been known to switch things up via update and break our flow.  Is it possible that this was a change to the operating system?  You *might not* get that functionality back. :(  Hopefully someone has more insight than I do.  Buena suerte primo.